# Neural Net advances in textual entailment and mathematical semantics/logic view on it

Tags: logic, formal-semantics, entailment

I wonder if researchers working on textual entailment using explicit modelling tools (mathematical semantics / logic /formal semantics) have an explanation of recent success of neural networks in textual entailment ([GLUE Benchmark](https://gluebenchmark.com/leaderboard))? Any links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not researching formal semantics (syntax, speech understanding and production are my areas), and I do apply and ML methods and have a first person knowledge of them. If nobody writes an answer in a day more, I will. It's not going to be specific, naturally, but I can explain why neural nets are good at *X* for almost any *X*, for a specific notion "being good at *X*." Please tag me if it slips off my radar.